# Copied text not kept in Clipboard when form is closed VB6

Tags: vba, windows-7, vb6, richtextbox

I'm maintaining an old **VB6 application** that experience some issues with copy/paste when running under windows 7. A couple of forms has a **RichTextBox** control from where you can **no longer copy text** (ctr-c).

This is what i have learned:

- If the form is kept open the copy/paste works fine but as soon as the
  form closes the Clipboard seems to be cleared out.
- It works fine with ordinary text boxes it's just the RichTextBox that
  has this problem.
- It works fine in the IDE but when compiled to a exe this problem
  surface.
- I have another windows 7 machine (32bit) where everything works as expected.

The application uses Microsoft's Richtx32.ocx (v6.1.97.82) for the rihtext control. I'm running windows 7 64bit version.

I'm really thankful for any help with this since I'm getting kind of desperate right now.

**Edit:**
If I copy something before I open the form and later close the same form the text is still in the clipboard so my form is not clearing the clipboard instead it seems like a memory management issue? Could it be the "GC" clearing the clipboard if the unused object (the textbox) has text in it?

Comment: Is `ver. 6.1.97.82` vanilla SP6? Have you tried the version coming with CU rollup (`ver. 6.1.98.16`)? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/957924

Comment: Are you saying that the rich text box is not setting text on the clipboard at all? In which case, that could be a bug with the underlying rich text control. Maybe it isn't properly 64-bit compatible?

Comment: Using the very same version of this OCX I have tried a sample program on Windows Home Server 2011 (which only comes in 64-bit and is a basically server edition of Win7).  No problems.  It even works if I have copied a section of the rich text that contains images.  I started the VB6 program, loaded an RTF file, selected a section of the text, copied it, then ended the program.  Fired up WordPad and pasted the text just fine.

Comment: @MarkBertenshaw As long as the form with the rtf control is open everything works fine but when I close the form the copied text is cleared out. However it doesn't clear the clipboard unless I copy something from the specific form. Really weird.

Comment: @Bob77 OK then it might not be the dll that's the problem. Has VB6 some kind of service pack I missed to install or something? In my 32-bit dev environment everything works as expected and I recently moved the environment to my current machine and maybe I missed to install a patch or something? On the other hand. When I compile on my new machine and run it on the old one everything works fine again so it must be a dll problem right?

Comment: It seems more likely you had a bug where you were clearing the clipboard but later you removed that line of code.

Answer (score 1):

It would be a good idea if you find out exactly at what point the data gets "cleared out". Put code before your Me.Hide or Unload Me statement, in the Form_Unload statement, and at some point after the form has been cleared down to execute:

```
Clipboard.GetFormat(vbCFRTF)
```

This will tell you at what point the clipboard doesn't detect the text.

In the meantime, you could save the data in a global variable, or pass it back as a parameter at the last point that the clipboard *is* ok, and then if necessary, execute at a point after the form is closed:

```
Clipboard.Clear
Clipboard.SetText sRichText, vbCFRTF
```

Another thing, have you tried running with Windows XP SP3 compatibility?

Comment: I'm trying the approach of storing the data i a global variable but I need to capture the text on ctrl-c. Is it possible to listen to ctrl-c keystrokes in a global context and not in a specific control or form?

Comment: You could do Win32 API key stroke hooking, but that would be inadvisable. I would try to find out more about what leads up to this issue. For instance, what is on the clipboard when your Rich Text "disappears" from the clipboard? Could some other thread or process be using the clipboard for its own purposes? BTW - Did you set the Windows compatibility settings?

Comment: OK. Yes, I tried windows compatibility with no luck. The clipboard seems to clear on Form_Unload. After that my clipboard is empty. I will do some further investigation.